# Infer function signature if keyof

Tags: typescript

I am trying to define a type `Column` that has the `render` function signature change depending on if `name` is `keyof Row` or not, via the following addition (note `name?: string`):

```
 | {
    name?: string
    render: (payload: { row: Row }) => string
}
```

Note that removing the above ^ from the code example makes everything work as expected, **as long as `name` is `keyof Row`**

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do, or is this a typescript limitation? Here's the complete code example:

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=3#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB2AeASnA7gPigF4oBvAKCigG0BpKASzSgGsIQ4AzKHXAXQBcZSlShoAhighDaIqgCcIaACYR5AfiEAKMOJAI445UNJQAbuOTSeeOnwA0UeXiG8oAXwCUxQgGdg8kwA5iLu5O7UbBzcvHxQAD7ComKS1v6BaCHJiipq2rr6hsZkTi42uB7eRH4BweHk5EzAapziAMbQALIgbhRUnHBwQul1YeRtcGj+UBPI6L5C8HOY3bz41HEk1H0pUkIA5ANw+-YiOary2qbOuI4WVpU+5pZIEOGOOxJ7UPtocMAASTQqzwJzOSguV1KFS8T1McicEGASHkzH2AAsIAgDPtQuE+EA)

```
type Column<Row> = {
  [K in keyof Row]: {
    name: K
    render?: (payload: { value: Row[K], row: Row }) => string
  }
}[keyof Row] | {
    name?: string
    render: (payload: { row: Row }) => string
}

interface MyRow {
  foo: string
}

const columns: Column<MyRow>[] = [{
  name: 'foo',
  render: ({ row, value }) => value
}, {
  name: 'notInMyRow',
  render: ({ row }) => { 
    return 'hello'
  }
}]
```

Relevant error:
`Binding element 'row' implicitly has an 'any' type.(7031)`

Comment: [Please consider replacing/supplementing images of code/errors with plain text versions.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Its in the image alt text, but I'll add it inline

Comment: The only problem I see here is that the compiler is balking at contextual typing of `row` and `value` since you technically have a union of function types (after all, `"foo"` is `string` just as well as it's `keyof MyRow`).  You could annotate types explicitly, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w18ryW) to make the errors go away.  If you don't want to do this, you could use a helper function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKkjyW) to coax the desired contextual inference from the compiler.  If this accurately represents your issue, I'll be happy to write up an answer. Let me know.